# shell script to copy files from one directory to another

Tags: shell, scripting, terminal

Trying to write a simple script to copy some files in OS X 10.9.
Here's the content..

```
SRC_DIR="~/Library/Preferences-Old"

DST_DIR="~/Library/Preferences"

FILEN="test.txt"

cp $SRC_DIR/$FILEN $DST_DIR
```

Gives me the output:

```
cp: ~/Library/Preferences-Old/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Of course, the above is wrong. The exact same cp command in terminal directly does the trick. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: actually removing all the quotes resolved the problem! Don't know exactly what's going on here..

Comment: It's all about understanding quoting. Read e.g. [bash quoting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: @apil.tamang [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) helpfully points to the problem saying  "[Note that ~ does not expand in quotes.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2088)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~` is one of the few exceptions to the rule "When in doubt, quote". As others have pointed out, a quoted `~` is not subject to expansion. However, you can still quote the *rest* of the string:

```
SRC_DIR=~"/Library/Preferences-Old"
DST_DIR=~"/Library/Preferences"
```

Note that depending on the values assigned to the two `*_DIR` variables, it's not enough to quote the values being assigned; you still need to quote their expansions.

```
FILEN="test.txt"

cp "$SRC_DIR/$FILEN" "$DST_DIR"
```

Answer (score 6):

Your double-quotes are preventing the shell from converting your `~` into an actual path. Observe:

```
$ echo ~
/home/politank_z

$ echo "~"
~
```

`~` isn't an actual location, it is shorthand for the path of your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned double-quotes disabled `~` expansion.

Better approach is to use `HOME` variable:

```
SRC_DIR="$HOME/Library/Preferences-Old"
DST_DIR="$HOME/Library/Preferences"
```